# Show Matrix array in table html with python

Tags: python, jquery, arrays, matrix

I am new in python and I am trying to show a matrix array in a table, I have my code in jQuery but I don't know how to do the same code to python, this is my code:

```
<html>
  <body>
       <table id='tb1' style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
           <tbody id='tb'>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </body>
</html>

$('#tb').ready(     
    function() {
    console.log('table loaded');
    var ar = [["1","3","22","7"],["2","4","6","8"],["3","66","16","9"],["3322","1112","2222","1231"]];
    for(var j=0;j<ar.length;j++){
      $('#tb').append('<tr>');
      for(var k=0;k<ar.length;k++){                
        $('#tb').append('<td style="border: 1px solid #666666;padding:2px;">'+
                          '<a href="#" style="display:block; border-radius: 3px;background-color: #149bb2;font-weight: 500;color: white;padding: 10px 35px;font-size: 12px;cursor: pointer;text-decoration: none; text-align:center;">'+
                            ar[k][j]+
                          '</a>'+
                        '</td>');
      }             
      $('#tb').append('</tr>');
    }
});
```

Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `Jinja Template`?

Comment: No, I need that in python :(

Comment: This is quite broad/vague. Can you be more specific? What exactly are you trying to do, and what issue are you encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ar = [["1","3","22","7"],["2","4","6","8"],["3","66","16","9"],["3322","1112","2222","1231"]]

html = """<html><body><table id='tb1' style="width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;"><tbody id='tb'>{}</tbody></table></body></html>"""

r = ''
for x in range(len(ar)):
    r+=('<tr>{}</tr>'.format(
                        ''.join(["""<td style="border: 1px solid #666666;padding:2px;"><a href="#" style="display:block; border-radius: 3px;background-color: #149bb2;font-weight: 500;color: white;padding: 10px 35px;font-size: 12px;cursor: pointer;text-decoration: none; text-align:center;">{}</a></td>""".format(l[x]) for l in ar])))

html = html.format(r)

with open('table.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```